# Does "set = {}" instead of "set.clear()" cause a memory leak in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, set

I have a non-empty set `x` in python. Instead of using a clearing method like `x.clear()`, if I use `x = {}`, it will get rid of the values for `x`, but will it cause a memory leak? I think the values were stored somewhere and I am not clearing them, and I can't access them later as well.

Comment: It should be trivial to write two examples where you stress test the loop and check memory consumption for both cases

Comment: In CPython, if there are no other references, the object is deleted immediately (not eventually or later) by reference counting. If you want to check this for yourseld, you may be interested in [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

Comment: Realize that {} is an empty dictionary, not an empty set. I presume you mean `x = set()`

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a significant difference. You can easily check this using [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/)

```
# debug.py
import sys

from memory_profiler import profile


@profile
def test1():
    result = set()
    for i in range(500000):
        result.add(i * i)

    result = set()  # set instead of dict
    return result


@profile
def test2():
    result = set()
    for i in range(500000):
        result.add(i * i)

    result.clear()
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    locals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

run `python debug.py test1`:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     6     19.5 MiB     19.5 MiB           1   @profile
     7                                         def test1():
     8     19.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       result = set()
     9     51.2 MiB     14.9 MiB      500001       for i in range(500000):
    10     51.2 MiB     16.7 MiB      500000           result.add(i * i)
    11                                         
    12     22.4 MiB    -28.8 MiB           1       result = set()   <--- AFTER REASSIGN
    13     22.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return result
```

run `python debug.py test2`:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    16     19.3 MiB     19.3 MiB           1   @profile
    17                                         def test2():
    18     19.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       result = set()
    19     51.0 MiB     15.2 MiB      500001       for i in range(500000):
    20     51.0 MiB     16.5 MiB      500000           result.add(i * i)
    21                                         
    22     22.2 MiB    -28.8 MiB           1       result.clear()   <-- AFTER CLEAR
    23     22.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return result
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, curly braces {} are used to define both dictionaries and sets, depending on the context.

Using `set = {}` instead of `set.clear()` doesn't cause a memory leak as described in other answers.
But it can lead to unintended consequences of rebinding the variable to a new empty dictionary. If you want to clear the set in-place and keep the same set object, use `set.clear()`. If you need to create a new empty set, use set() or set = set().

```
my_set = {1, 2, 3}
print(my_set)  # Output: {1, 2, 3}
my_set = {}  # Rebinding to an empty dictionary
print(my_set)  # Output: {}
```

You can see in below code that my_set is still bound to set type but in above code it's bind to empty dictionary.

```
my_set = {1, 2, 3}
print(my_set)  # Output: {1, 2, 3}
my_set.clear()  # Clear the set in-place
print(my_set)  # Output: set()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what being said,
it depends, if you have another reference on the set somewhere, and you will not be using the set values. yes, you will be leaking memory as here:

```
my_set = {}
my_set2 = my_set
# some lines of code
my_set = {} # at this level there are still a reference on the set, so it won't be garbage collected and thus there will be a leak
```

But otherwise, if that was the only reference to the set, the old one will be garbage collected and there will be no noticable diferrence.
But it is safer to use clear, just in case there are some references hanging out there